# Editing records in a bootstrap modal in Laravel

Tags: forms, twitter-bootstrap, laravel, modal-dialog

I have a named route `admin.resources.index` which lists all the records from `resources` table in the form of a list via `foreach` . Each record in the list there is `Edit Resource` button.

```
// admin/resources/index.blade.php  

@foreach ($resources as $resource)
      <button class="btn bg-blue waves-effect res-edit-profile-btn" href="{{ route( 'admin.resources.index', $resource ) }}" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editModal">Edit Resource</button>
@endforeach
```

And a `editModal` on the same page ( admin/resources/index.blade.php ) which I want to populate with values from `resource` object.

**ISSUE**

The problem is the `editModal` is opened with all the contents of `admin/resources/index.blade.php` rather just than editModal content only.

[image: laravel_modal_question_stack_img]

These type of problems come up when there is issue with `html`. A missing closing element tags. But I have already verified the markup.

Comment: why you are loading the same parent url `{{ route( 'admin.resources.index', $resource ) }}` in modal again. Shouldn't it be different?

Comment: @FarooqKhan, I want to open the modal box in the same page.

Comment: Logically it should load complete URL (with resources), unless you have custom conditions with in , based on data passed to view

Comment: You are right, This is the question. How can I only load the contents of editModal.

Comment: Render `@modal` section when `$resource` is there, else render normal content. Your issue is not really related to bootstrap, You can fix it using `blade` conditions.

Comment: That is one good option. But is there a way I don't have to load the the URL, I can just pass the resource object to modal. Because this is how modal works we never reload the page for modal.

Comment: It depends on your Stack. What are you using at the front-end .. angular or just plain JS?

Comment: @FarooqKhan, I am using jquery. BTW, I thought of a work around and it worked. I will post an answer soon.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround is to use `data-` attributes. We can dynamically generate the `data-target` attribute on the our button like

```
<button class="btn bg-blue waves-effect res-edit-profile-btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editModal-{{ $resource['resource_id'] }}">Edit Resource </button>
```

Also generate your modal using `foreach`. This will be like every generated button link will have its own modal.

```
@foreach ($resources as $resource)

<div class="modal fade" id="editModal-{{ $resource['resource_id'] }}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">

 // Other modal html here

</div>
@endforeach
```

**IMPORTANT**

This solution generates a lot of markup using `foreach` i.e for every record there is complete modal markup. Which might effect the page performance. If you have anything better. Please update here for future reference.

Comment: This will eventually multiply your page-load time as there will be extra modals in your page against each foreach item.right?

Comment: Yes I already have added the IMPORTANT section above for this reason. Hence stated it as a workaround. Will work on this.

Comment: I have a similar issue - just wondering if you found a better solution in the end?